# Liter/100 km or km/Liter

Tags: usage

In America we say the fuel economy of car as miles/gallon (miles per gallon). I know in some countries people use Liter/100 km (liter per 100 km). Some countries use km/Liter (km per liter).

My question is: which format Germany people use?

L/100 km or km/L?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Germany it's definitely l/100 km (note that Liter is abbreviated with a lowercase l). (I'd say that in most of western Europe it's that way, maybe different in the UK.)

To clarify: according to wikipedia the UK also uses mpg, but due to different definitions of gallon, american mpg are different than british mpg. And as far as I know noone in the world uses km/l - it's either mpg (US or UK) or l/100 km, but this is from my personal experience and may be wrong.

Comment: Note that accordingly the measure is usually not labelled something meaning ‘fuel economy’ or ‘motor efficiency’ in German, but _Verbrauch_ ‘consumption’ (often found in compounds like _Spritverbrauch, Benzinverbrauch, Kraftstoffverbrauch_). Officially, uppercase ‘L’ is an accepted alternative symbol for liter, but it’s rarely found in German texts and labels.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre#Symbol for _l_ vs. _L_.

Comment: The upper-/lowercase is thing is starting to develop into a thread on its own :-) The Duden (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Liter) only mentions the lowercase "L"

Answer (score 3):

If you **buy** a car, you will get l/100km indications, possibly separated according to usage scenario.

If you **rent** a car (possibly due to international harmonization) the km per liter specification is possible if not likely, see

[image: here]

Comment: Nice find, never encountered this and would've bet on a localization bug.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, `l/100 km` can be applied with respect to a region (like in town, out of town).

```
Kraftstoffverbrauch innerorts, l/100 km: 6,6 - 6,5
Kraftstoffverbrauch außerorts, l/100 km: 4,7 - 4,6
Kraftstoffverbrauch kombiniert, l/100 km: 5,4 - 5,3
```

Source: [A German car](http://m.volkswagen.de/de/models/the-beetle/verbrauch.opt.html)